# Getting a CORS error when trying to onboard users to Stripe Connect with Node.js

Tags: node.js, cors, stripe-payments

I am trying to set up our platform to allow users to be able to connect from our platform using Stripe Connect.

I am following the stripe-examples/connect-onboarding-for-standard that is linked to the documentation.  Here is the code that I am using.

```
app.get("/api/stripe/onboard-user/refresh", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.session.accountID) {
    res.redirect("/");
    return;
  }

  try {
    const { accountID } = req.session;
    const origin = `${req.secure ? "https://" : "https://"}${req.headers.host}`;

    const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
      type: "account_onboarding",
      account: account.id,
      refresh_url: `${origin}/api/stripe/onboard-user/refresh`,
      return_url: `${origin}/settings/invoicing`,
    });

    res.redirect(303, accountLink.url);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      error: err.message,
    });
  }
});
```

Every thing works find down to the res.redirect(303, accountLink.url);  At that point it throws an error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://connect.stripe.com/setup/s/1JdWa4pVJGhR' (redirected from 'https://localhost:4200/api/stripe/onboard-user') from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I can pull the url from the error message and put it in a browser and it go to the page fine and I can finish the process.  I have tried changing headers but have not found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error often happens because your client-side code is making a GET request to your server, expecting a JSON response in an AJAX/fetch call, but your server is redirecting directly. That fails since the browser doesn't know what to do in this situation.

Usually, what you need to do is change your client-side call to not do a `fetch()` or AJAX equivalent and instead do a full page submission to your endpoint that will then redirect. Alternatively, you need to return the URL in your Node.js code instead of the redirect and have your client extract the URL from the response and redirect.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed.  I just return the url from the server to the client and had the client go to the url and it works great.  Thanks again.

Comment: koopajah, could you add a small example to help future readers know what "do a full page submission to your endpoint" means?

Comment: Can you also explain why "the browser doesn't know what to do in this situation"? It seems obvious: if a redirect is returned, redirect, no?

Comment: It isn't obvious, you are redirecting but the browser is in the middle of processing a response from your server and is expected to call your callback/promise to tell you what the server responded with. If it redirected, your code would never run which could be problematic. I don't think adding an example is the best option here as Stripe has an end to end quickstart with exactly that flow https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart