# Laravel redirect to stripe session URL

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, stripe-payments

After creating a session for Stripe checkout in my controller, I am trying to redirect by using

```
return redirect($session->url);
```

but I keep getting a CORS error.

I can add the URL and go there manually without any issue.

However, according to this post

> [Getting a CORS error when trying to onboard users to Stripe Connect with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886233/getting-a-cors-error-when-trying-to-onboard-users-to-stripe-connect-with-node-js)

the solution is to return the URL from the server to the client and have him redirect from there.

Can anybody explain to me how to actually do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

> the solution is to return the URL from the server to the client and have him redirect from there

You may return the URL instead of a redirect:

```
return response()->json([
    'redirect_url' => $session->url
]);
```

And redirect the user from the client.
You will have the redirect url in the JSON response. Handle it accordingly.

Assuming your client is using AJAX, you may redirect the user using:

```
success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = data.redirect_url;
}
```

Comment: @vStubbs please post the solution as an answer instead of updating this.